# Random Variable in Index: Summation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

Let $X_i, Y$ be independent random variables both taking values in $\mathbb{N}$. Assume further that the $X_i´s$ are identical distributed. Then for $ 0 < A < \infty $ I want to compute the following sum.

$$ \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^Y X_i \leq A) $$

I would do this as follows:

$$ \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^Y X_i \leq A)= \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^Y X_i \leq A | Y = n) = \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq A)= n \mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq A) $$

and thus

$$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^Y X_i \leq A | Y) = \mathbb{P}(Y) \nobreakspace \mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq A)  $$

which finally leads to

$$ \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^Y X_i \leq A) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y=i) \nobreakspace i \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq A) $$

Am I correct? I used Walds formula for inspiration.

Comment: Should your first equality be $\displaystyle\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^Y X_i \leq A\right)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq A \,\bigg|\, Y = n\right) \mathbb{P}(Y = n)$ ?

Comment: Yes you are right. I forgot the last term... But the result should be correct anyway right?

Comment: Roll a dice twice. The chance that the sum is $\le 6$, is certainly not $2$.

Comment: Do you really need to compute the probability? For a lower bound, you can use markov's inequality.

Comment: Thanks a lot. A lower bound would be fine. I think I got it. Using Markovs inequality and Walds formula I get: $ \mathbb{P} (\sum_{i=1}^Y X_i \leq A) = 1 - \mathbb{P} (\sum_{i=1}^Y X_i > A) \leq 1 - \frac{E ( \sum_{i=1}^Y X_i)}{A} = 1 - \frac{E(Y) E(X_1)}{A} $ What do you think?

Comment: @Jack_Stiller10 that's what I have in mind. You can also try to apply Walds inequality on $Z_1 = 1_{X_1 \le A}$ and $Z_{n} = 1_{S_{n} \le A} - Z_{n-1}$ with $S_{n} = X_1+\dotsb+X_n$.

Comment: Why do you set $ Z_n = 1_{S_n \leq A} - Z_{n-1}$. Isn´t $Z_n = 1_{S_n \leq A}$ sufficient?

Comment: Sorry, I got your point. I try to work it out and the post again.

Comment: Setting like you did in your comment yields: $ \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^Y X_i \leq A) = \mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^Y Z_i) $ and thus $ \mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^Y Z_i) = \mathbb{E}(Y) \mathbb{E}(Z_1) =  \mathbb{E}(Y) \mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq A) $ Right?

Comment: @Jack_Stiller10 i pretty sure that the $Z_n$'s aren't iid.